# How to increase the height of a dojo Enhanced datagrid' s each row when grid div increased

Tags: html, css, jsp, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have a DOJO enhanced grid in my web-page. I am trying to apply a full screen on it using HTML5 full screen API. It is working fine but the height and width are not enlarged in full screen view. THis is the code I am having now. What are the changes I have to make to adjust the height and width on full screen?

```
    function resizeGrid() {
     dijit.byId('grid1').autoHeight = false;
     dijit.byId('grid1').autoWidth = false;
                 var x= dijit.byId('grid1');
     var contentBox = dojo.contentBox(x);
    contentBox = dojo.setContentSize(dojo.byId("grid1"), {t: 20, l: 30, h: 500, w: 830});
    grid.update();
}

    var gridLayout = [ 
    { name: "IP/Phone No.", classes: "title", field: "devType", fields:['devType', 'name'], formatter:formatLink1,styles: 'text-align: center;', width: "150px"},
    { name: 'Status', classes: "title", field: "statusMessageFull", fields:['statusMessageFull', 'statusMessageColor'], formatter:formatLink,styles: 'text-align: center;', width: "150px"},
    { name: "I/P Voltage (V)", classes: "title",field: "mainsVoltage",styles: 'text-align: center;', width: "80px" }];
```

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/LpD4S/7/